# Integration testing, how exactly

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a hard time figuring out how you actually do integration tests
Is it still automated test with JUnit, NUnit or whatever, or is it just using the program (it has a gui) an making sure that everything works?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [what-kinds-of-tests-are-there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123197/what-kinds-of-tests-are-there/3123232#3123232) and [whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test)

GUI testing can be listed in system testing, acceptance testing. 
GUI test tool mostly depends on type of UI (Web/Desktop/Mobile). e.g. for web testing you can evaluate good open source tools like selenium.